# In Qur'an 7:27, why does Allah assign devils to those who disbelieve?

Tags: quran, tafseer, sunni, surat-al-araf

In [Quran 7:27](https://quran.com/7/27) Allah SWT states

> Pickthall:  "O Children of Adam! Let not Satan seduce you as he caused your (first) parents to go forth from the Garden and tore off from them their robe (of innocence) that he might manifest their shame to them. Lo! he seeth you, he and his tribe, from whence ye see him not. Lo! We have made the devils protecting friends for those who believe not."

Why does Allah Almighty assign devils to those who disbelieve in Allah's revelations?

Comment: Is there a reason for the Sunni tag?

Comment: @Rebecca J. Stones I added a Sunni tag because I follow the Sunni branch of Islam

Comment: Disbelievers choose evil so the devils invite them to more evil which translates to more punishment.